InaccessibleObjectException when ejb3 standalone application remotely calls the ejbs in wildfly 31 server
Iam calling ejb3 remotely through lookup jndi from standalone application to  that ejbs are at  wildfly 31 server.
note:

this code is working when i started wildfly server 31

 Context  ctxt = null;
DomesticPOSTransactionFacade domesticPOSTransactionFacade=null;

Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.wildfly.naming.client.WildFlyInitialContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"http-remoting://10.10.21.29:8080");
            ctxt = new  InitialContext(env);
domesticPOSTransactionFacade = (DomesticPOSTransactionFacade)ctxt.lookup("ejb:/airmanage/DomesticColumbiaPOSTransFacadeBean!"+DomesticColumbiaPOSTransFacade.class.getName());


but when I run as java
I am getting this exception


java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field
private static final java.lang.reflect.Method jdk.proxy2.$Proxy3.m0
accessible: module jdk.proxy2 does not "opens jdk.proxy2" to unnamed
module @41a2befb Exception while accessing getInAgentObj

